# import mongodb database to mongolab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

i have export mongoDB from local Database and it's in following format and save as CSV file.

```
_id,accomodation,state,user
ObjectId(565dae266dbda6964f061d99),No,California,ObjectId(5651fb48b0dfa73c134df161)
```

Then i try to run mongoimport with following command

```
 mongoimport -h hostname -d dbname -c collectionname -u username
 -p password --file filename.csv --type csv --headerline
```

import success but Mongolab store DB in strict mode as i read so they store

```
ObjectId(565dae266dbda6964f061d99)  in this format 
"_id": {
        "$oid": "565dae266dbda6964f061d99"
    }
```

But the Data i imported it just store as ObjectId(565dae266dbda6964f061d99)...i want to know how i can import that save in safe mode it my all the ObjectID data store in  "$oid": "565dae266dbda6964f061d99" format in my mongolabDb.

Let me know if you have any question..

Thanks.

Comment: A quick clarification: MongoLab does not store data in strict JSON, all MongoDB data is still stored as BSON. However the document editor in the web UI is a JSON editor, and therefore ObjectId's must be viewed and edited in a JSON format, using strict MongoDB extended JSON. You'll notice if you connect to your MongoLab database via the mongo administrative shell and query for data, these _id values will display as ObjectId's (because the shell is a JavaScript interpreter and doesn't enforce strict JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly note in your question, MongoLab uses [Strict MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) so Object IDs are represented like that:

```
{ "$oid": "<id>" }
```

There's no way of changing this on the hosted service.

Comment: i don't sure but query work locally on this Data {
    "_id": "ObjectId(565dae266dbda6964f061d9a)",
    "accomodation": "No",
    "user": "ObjectId(5651fb48b0dfa73c134df161)"
}   but once we put same on mongolab query doesn't work once i change ObjectId with $oid then it start working...

Comment: are you using the console or an ORM?

Comment: ah ok, in the console you will have to use (as you saw)  $oid - most ORMs will handle this for you automatically though

Comment: in my collection i have one fields  "user": "ObjectId(5651fb48b0dfa73c134df161)" i just change userID and now data comes through with ObjectId as well....i don't know why user key name conflict.....any way thanks :)

Comment: @sonukumar no problem, glad I could help